# getContext() in A Fragment when I handler SoundPool (want to play the sound files from database)

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

My user interface application has a volume to play a sound file when the user press. This is A Fragment which holder the volume. 
I contributed a SoundManager class to perform the following funcions: construct, load and play the soundpool Object

SoundManager.java

```
public class SoundManager {

    private SoundManager soundManager;
    SoundPool soundPool;

    int CLICK_SOUND;


    public SoundManager(){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            soundPool = (new SoundPool.Builder()).setMaxStreams(1).build();
        }else{
            soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 5);
        }
    }

    public void loadSound(Context context, int resID){
        CLICK_SOUND = soundPool.load(context, resID, 1);
        // CLICK_SOUND1 = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.vegetable, 1);
        // load other sound if you like
    }

    public void playClickSound(){
        soundPool.play(CLICK_SOUND, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
    }
}
```

Then, In the Fragment.java. inside  `@override onCreateView` i used `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`  to get Context of this Fragment.

if I put  `soundManager.loadSound(context,resID)` below the `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` Certainly the sound was play when user clikced the volume button.
 However, when i put `soundManager.loadSound(context,resID)` inside the `OnClick()` function, The Sound was not play.
how can i fix it

Fragment.java

```
> .....inside onCreatView(...)
context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    final SoundManager soundManager=new SoundManager();
    //soundManager.loadSound(context,resID);// Okay, Sound is run...

        btnVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String action="handlerSoundVolume";
                //LoadSound in here is not active...????
                soundManager.loadSound(context,resID);
                soundManager.playClickSound();
                mainRoundMode4.itemClicked(action,"");
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Ali Khaki.
How nice of you. I am from VietNam, but my English is not good. I 'll improve

Comment: This should have worked, it seems likely that the error is in code not posted here. How did you manage to make `context` available inside `onClick()` without declaring it `final`?

Comment: Oke guy, I already have thrown.But, The slund file is not active...

Answer (score 0):

Change `context=getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to `context = getContext();`